# how to execute MongoDB Query in RDBMS Driver way

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java, mongo-java-driver

In RDMS if I have to execute "Select emp_name from Employee where empid=100". I would do this,

```
String query = "Select emp_name from Employee where empid=100"
    Statement stmt = DriverManager.getConnection(db, user, password).createStatement();
    result = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

How can I do the same in MongoDB where I get the query like "Employee.find({'empid:1000'},{emp_name:1})

Currently this is the code I'm using, in which I have to write the 'where' and 'select' part I mean dbObj(where) and projectdbObj(projecttion Or select part) separately.

```
DBObject dbObj = (DBObject)  JSON.parse("{'employee.empid':'1000'}");
        DBObject projectdbObj = (DBObject)  JSON.parse("{'emp_name':1}");
        try{
            MongoCollection<Document> coll = mongoClient.getDatabase("Company" ).getCollection("Employee");
            FindIterable<Document> cursor = coll.find((Bson) dbObj).projection((Bson) projectdbObj);
            cursor.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
                @Override
                public void apply(final Document document) {
                    System.out.print(document);
                }
            });

        }
```

Please help to optimize the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Filters builder to build 'where' part and Projections builder to build 'select' part in MongoDB 3.0 without create object separately. Please refer below eg:

```
FindIterable<Document> cursor = coll.find(Filters.eq("employee.empid",1000)).projection(Projections.fields(Projections.include("emp_name"),Projections.excludeId());
```